# WebStorm: configure Prettier to use tabs?

Tags: webstorm, prettier

The [Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tabs) say to use `--use-tabs` to override the default behavior. WebStorm automatically populated the Prettier package:

[image]

That's a folder. I tried changing it to `npm\prettier.cmd` and adding the switch, but that doesn't work (It just turns red).

How can I set WebStorm to use tabs with Prettier?

Comment: By using Prettier config file perhaps? https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: Where would I place the config file if I wanted it global? What do I add to the config file to make this change? I don't think either of these questions are answered in the docs...

Answer (score 1):

If your project has a *.editorconfig* file, you can override the *indent_style* setting in there.

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*]
indent_size = 4
indent_style = tab
```

I found these resources helpful too:

- https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tabs
- https://editorconfig.org/

Comment: best to include the relevant section from these links inside the answer, so that if the pages behind these links go down, the community can still benefit from your answer

Answer (score 0):

Due to https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/2434 fix, Prettier (even global!) uses configuration file nearest to current file (up the directory tree) when formatting.

So, you can install it globally and configure it in your project, by adding the corresponding `.prettierrc` file or `"prettier"` section in project `package.json`.

Comment: I have created a CLI for helping to create the `.prettierrc`. I leave the link to the tool in case that it can be useful for more people https://github.com/gabrielperales/prettier-init