# Making Webstorm use single quotes for prettier

Tags: webstorm, prettier

I am looking for a way to change the double quotes (default behavior) to single quotes. I've read the docs and tried to search online but the normal way of doing it does not seem to work.

I've adapted the `package.json` in various ways, none have worked and this is my latest try:

```
"prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true
},
```

I don't know how to do it. The documentation is pretty bad on this one. They mention configs as well but I wouldn't know how to place them either.

Someone with a similar question:
[WebStorm: configure Prettier to use tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521161/webstorm-configure-prettier-to-use-tabs)

Comment: Not worth posting an answer, by my issue was that I just had to restart Webstorm a handful of times after configuring my packages properly.

Answer (score 20):

WebStorm allows importing code style preferences from prettier. For example:

[image]

press **Yes** to get settings applied - they will be used when you reformat your code with **Code | Reformat code**, as well as when running **Reformat with Prettier** action

Edit:
Due to https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/2434 fix, Prettier (even global!) uses configuration file nearest to current file (up the directory tree) when formatting.

So, you can install it globally and configure it in your project, by adding the corresponding `.prettierrc` file or `"prettier"` section in project `package.json`.

Comment: It's not at all obvious how to use this though.  Your example shows a screen where the IDE is asking whether or not to use prettier, but I've never seen it do that and have no idea how to provoke that behavior.  And while I can find the settings page that says to use prettier, as far as I can tell that setting is ignored.  Making changes to the .prettierrc file has zero impact on how code is reformatted.

Comment: Oh - there's a bug in WebStorm Build #WS-212.5457.55.  If you don't have your node interpreter configured correctly, and you do have everything set up to use prettier, it will fail to use prettier and then fall back to its builtin reformatting support without any notice to the user that prettier wasn't used.

Answer (score 3):

Your config looks ok. Try **re-applying the Prettier rules**. Webstorm should adjust its own rules.

How to do it:

1. Open Actions <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Find `Apply Prettier Code Style Rules`

The official Webstorm docu [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#7fce4943).

---

PS: Sometimes also restart helps and sometimes it just takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

I created a local `.prettierrc` file in my WebStorm project root directory, and when I saved a .js file, it did not use those config settings.  Then I renamed the file `.prettierrc.json` and it worked.

```
{
    "singleQuote": true
}
```